# DOB Validation with three fields in magento2

Tags: magento2, form-validation

I need to change the "date of birth" field from date picker to three fields with validation.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

modified the below files 
replace full code in dob.phtml

```
<?php 
         $dob=$block->getDate();
         $year='';
         $smonth='';
         $day='';
         if($dob){
         $dateofbirth = explode("-", $dob);
         $year=$dateofbirth[0];
         $smonth=$dateofbirth[1];
         $day=$dateofbirth[2];
       }
?>


<div class="field dob customer-dob">
            <label for="dob" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Date of birth') ?></span>
            <span class="optional"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('(optional)') ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
            <input type="hidden" class="" value="<?php echo $dob; ?>" id="dob" name="dob" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text"  value="<?php echo $day; ?>" name="date" id="dob_dd" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('dd') ?>" class="input-text validate-cdobd" placeholder="DD" style="width:20%"   maxlength="2" 
            onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,document.getElementById('dob_mm'))"/>

                <select id="dob_mm" name="month" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('mm') ?>"   style="width:20%;" class="select validate-cdobm">
                 <option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('MM') ?></option>
                <?php for($month=1;$month<=12;$month++):?>
                    <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($month) ?>" <?php if ($month == $smonth) echo ' selected="selected"' ?> ><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __($month) ?></option>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>

                <input type="text" maxlength="4" value="<?php echo $year; ?>"name="year" id="dob_yy" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('yy') ?>" class="validate-cdoby" placeholder="YYYY" style="width:20%" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,document.getElementById('gender'))"/>
                <div class="validate-custom"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearboth"></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

function moveOnMax(field, nextFieldID) { 
    if (field.value.length >= field.maxLength) { nextFieldID.focus(); } 
}

</script>
```

in edit.phtml add below script in the end of the file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery', // jquery Library
        'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
        'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
        'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
    ], function($){     

      var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
        var ignore = <?php echo $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null'; ?>;

        dataForm.mage('validation', {
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.prop('id').search('dob_dd') !== -1 || element.prop('id').search('dob_mm') !== -1 || element.prop('id').search('dob_yy') !== -1) {
                  var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                        errorClass = error.prop('class');
                    error.insertAfter($('.validate-custom'));
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
        <?php else: ?>
            ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
        <?php endif ?>
        });


         $.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-cdobd', function(value) {
            var postToRahaha = $("#dob_yy").val();
             var dayVal = $("#dob_dd").val(),
                    monthVal = $("#dob_mm").val(),
                    yearVal = $("#dob_yy").val(),
                    dobLength = dayVal.length + monthVal.length + yearVal.length;
                /* if (params[3] && dobLength === 0) {
                    this.dobErrorMessage = 'This is a required field.';
                    return false;
                }*/
                if (dobLength=== 0) {
                    return true;
                } 
                var day = parseInt(dayVal, 10) || 0,
                    month = parseInt(monthVal, 10) || 0,
                    year = parseInt(yearVal, 10) || 0,
                    curYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
                if (!day) {
                    this.dobErrorMessage = 'Please enter a valid full date.';
                    return false;
                }

                var validateDayInMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
                if (day < 1 || day > validateDayInMonth) {
                    var validDateMessage = $.mage.__('Please enter a valid day (1-%1).');
                    this.dobErrorMessage = validDateMessage.replace('%1', validateDayInMonth.toString());
                    return false;
                }
                var today = new Date(),
                    dateEntered = new Date();
                dateEntered.setFullYear(year, month - 1, day);
                if (dateEntered > today) {
                    this.dobErrorMessage = $.mage.__('Please enter a date from the past.');
                    return false;
                }


                return true;
        },
            function () {
                return this.dobErrorMessage;
            }
        );

         $.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-cdobm', function(value) {
            var postToRahaha = $("#dob_yy").val();
             var dayVal = $("#dob_dd").val(),
                    monthVal = $("#dob_mm").val(),
                    yearVal = $("#dob_yy").val(),
                    dobLength = dayVal.length + monthVal.length + yearVal.length;
                /* if (params[3] && dobLength === 0) {
                    this.dobErrorMessage = 'This is a required field.';
                    return false;
                }*/
                if (dobLength=== 0) {
                    return true;
                } 
                var day = parseInt(dayVal, 10) || 0,
                    month = parseInt(monthVal, 10) || 0,
                    year = parseInt(yearVal, 10) || 0,
                    curYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();

                if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
                    this.dobErrorMessage = 'Please select a valid month.';
                    return false;
                }


                return true;
        },
            function () {
                return this.dobErrorMessage;
            }
        );

         $.validator.addMethod(
        'validate-cdoby', function(value) {
            var postToRahaha = $("#dob_yy").val();
             var dayVal = $("#dob_dd").val(),
                    monthVal = $("#dob_mm").val(),
                    yearVal = $("#dob_yy").val(),
                    dobLength = dayVal.length + monthVal.length + yearVal.length;
                /* if (params[3] && dobLength === 0) {
                    this.dobErrorMessage = 'This is a required field.';
                    return false;
                }*/
                if (dobLength=== 0) {
                    return true;
                } 
                var day = parseInt(dayVal, 10) || 0,
                    month = parseInt(monthVal, 10) || 0,
                    year = parseInt(yearVal, 10) || 0,
                    curYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();


                var today = new Date(),
                    dateEntered = new Date();
                dateEntered.setFullYear(year, month - 1, day);
                if (!(dateEntered > today)){
                    if (year < 1900 || year > curYear) {
                        var validYearMessage = $.mage.__('Please enter a valid year (1900-%1).');
                        this.dobErrorMessage = validYearMessage.replace('%1', curYear.toString());
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                day = day % 10 === day ? '0' + day : day;
                month = month % 10 === month ? '0' + month : month;
                $('#dob').val(month + '/' + day + '/' + year);
                return true;
        },
            function () {
                return this.dobErrorMessage;
            }
        );


    });
    </script>
```

make sure dob attribute enable from admin :-)

Comment: Where is dob.phtml and edit.phtml

Comment: please get back to me 
magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\edit.phtml
magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\dob.phtml

Comment: Facing error while click on create account

ValueError: bcsub(): Argument #1 ($num1) is not well-formed in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Math.php:259
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Math.php(259): bcsub()