# Magento 2.3.4 Change date picker to 3 drop down dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: customer, date, registration, datepicker, customer-registration

How to change Magento 2 date picker to 3 drop down which allows users to pick date month and year.
Tried to follow this -> [DOB Validation with three fields in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114273/dob-validation-with-three-fields-in-magento2/114274)
But it didn't work and it wasn't explained.
Anyone know or any suggestion

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27655 that's the fix hope this helps you

Comment: Did you decide to ditch the 3 drop down fields?